# importing discord.js causes compile error "This module is declared with export="

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

I have 2 folders `classes` and `types` which contain various relavent files.
I know that discord.js is causing this issue as without the import statement the code runs just fine

I have a file that has a class with `export default` keyword and nothing to do with `discord.js` in the class.

At the top of the file. I have `import { Client } from "discord.js"` and this causes this error

```
node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.d.ts:170:5 - error TS18028: Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher.

170     #private;
        ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@sapphire/snowflake/dist/lib/Snowflake.d.ts:15:5 - error TS18028: Private identifiers are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 and higher.

15     #private;
       ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/undici/types/client.d.ts:5:8 - error TS1259: Module '"node_modules/undici/types/connector"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

5 import buildConnector, {connector} from "./connector";
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/undici/types/connector.d.ts:4:1
    4 export = buildConnector
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.

node_modules/undici/types/dispatcher.d.ts:6:13 - error TS1259: Module '"node_modules/undici/types/readable"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

6 import type BodyReadable from './readable'
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/undici/types/readable.d.ts:4:1
    4 export = BodyReadable
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.

node_modules/undici/types/handlers.d.ts:1:8 - error TS1259: Module '"node_modules/undici/types/dispatcher"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

1 import Dispatcher from "./dispatcher";
         ~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/undici/types/dispatcher.d.ts:12:1
    12 export = Dispatcher;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.


Found 5 errors in 5 files.

Errors  Files
     1  node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.d.ts:170
     1  node_modules/@sapphire/snowflake/dist/lib/Snowflake.d.ts:15
     1  node_modules/undici/types/client.d.ts:5
     1  node_modules/undici/types/dispatcher.d.ts:6
     1  node_modules/undici/types/handlers.d.ts:1
```

Without the single line import statement, there are 0 errors and weirdly i have "esModuleInterop" set to true in `tsconfig.json`

**What I've tried**

- Updating typescript
- Changing target (es5, es6, es2015, es2016) (with tsconfig and command line arguments)
- various tsconfig options(esModuleInterop, allowSyntheticDefaultImports, moduleResolution: node)
- adding directories to "include" in tsconfig

**My tsconfig file**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es2016", /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
        "module": "commonjs", /* Specify what module code is generated. */
        "esModuleInterop": true, /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
        "strict": true, /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
        "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
    },
    "include": [
        "classes",
        "types"
    ]
}
```

This error causes no red flags to show up in VSCode and the script still executes perfectly fine

**Minimum code to reproduce the error**

> npm init 
> tsc --init 
> npm i discord.js
>
> create a folder and then
> create a file inside that folder `index.ts`
>
> 1 line inside `index.ts` `import { Client } from "discord.js"`
>
> tsc index
> node index

Any ideas?

Comment: ES modules are the standard for JavaScript, while CommonJS is the default in Node.js. "esModuleInterop" : true, it should work fine. You can restart the project. Btw, I tried to produce the error and I got NO error.

Comment: Huh, thats very weird

Comment: quick hack can be using commonjs module system. const {Client} = require("discord.js") but it should be working either way.